# One Drive not working in Safari

Tags: macos, safari

I am using MacOS High Sierra (10.13.4) in 2016 MacBook Pro 15". 
Safari (Ver. 11.1 - *Latest as at 21st April 2018*) is not compatible with [One Drive](https://onedrive.live.com/). 

Note: This issue was not specific to this version. Previous versions had the same issue. JavaScript is enabled by default.

Incompatibilities:

- I could not share a specific folder/file because secondary click (right click) on the folder/file does nothing.
- Clicking The right side info icon (!) does nothing.
- Clicking on share/delete/download buttons at top of the file container does nothing.

Because of the above mentioned issues, One Drive makes no sense to use in Safari. However, in FireFox, it works perfect. Why Safari cannot handle One Drive? All the browsers seems to compatible with One Drive. But why Safari Does not? Or is this happening only to me?